# How to copy and paste from Excel to AG-Grid?

Tags: html, ag-grid

I want to copy and paste from Excel to AG-Grid. Therefore I use **processDataFromClipboard** from the docs (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/clipboard/).

```
processDataFromClipboard: function (params) {
                    var clipboardData = params.data;
                    var data = clipboardData.split('\n').map(function (row) {
                        return row.split('\t');
                    });
                    var firstRowIndex = params.rowStart;
                    var firstColIndex = params.columnStart;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                            var rowIndex = firstRowIndex + i;
                            var colIndex = firstColIndex + j;
                            gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({
                                update: [{ rowIndex: rowIndex, data: { [gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex].field]: data[i][j] } }]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
```

However it does not work. Pasting has no effect. What is wrong in my example? I put it on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/etaks90/m6oq2an4/